# Youtube api integration-Quota for playing single video

Tags: youtube-api

I use youtube-api to play youtube videos in my android app.

In https://console.developers.google.com ,they said

```
Free quota  
50,000,000 units/day
```

My aim is to play only videos, i dont want any other information from youtube.

so, How much units it will cost to play a single video in my app?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not youtube helpline.

Comment: Actually it is. YouTubes documentation says to post any questions on SO using the tags the OP has.

Comment: Hey anyone knows the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the data your call to the API request. The documentation states what the cost is. On average its 1 to read data

Use this link as it gives you a cost quota

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota

Tip. Only add part parameter you need

At 50,000,000 you don't have to worry though

Comment: Found that  ,Playing videos apparently doesn't cost anything. 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

API requests like videos.list cost 1 unit. 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Comment: Playing them doesn't but querying API to get the video ID for a URL does